# When I replace the mac m2 chip, I can't use mysql2 and I get an error symbol not found in flat namespace (_mysql_affected_rows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

Rails -> 7.0.3

MySQL -> 5.7.29

Ruby -> 3.1.1

Rvm -> 1.29.12

mysql2 -> 0.5

My project is trying to migrate m2 chips and when I try to run `rails s` I get the following error

```
`require': dlopen(/Users/list/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.4/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace (_mysql_affected_rows)
```

I have tried the following solutions, none of them work

```
bundle config build.mysql2 "--with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/mysql/include"
```

```
 gem install mysql2 -v '0.5' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-ldflags="-L/usr/local/mysql/lib -L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" --with-cppflags=-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include
```

How to solve this problem please?

Comment: Do you have your terminal set to "open with Rosetta"?